# How to find max and min from list in java

Tags: java, max, min

I need to find the maximum and minimum statistics for the student marks from a list. The list contains the student ID and the student Mark. Im not too sure how to do this.

This is the code for reading in the file and creating the list:

```
public void readFile(Scanner in)
{
    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = 0;

    try
    {
        File file = new File("Marks.txt");
        in = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("in " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        String studentRecord = in.nextLine();
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList(studentRecord.split(","));
        String inputStudentID = values.get(0);
        String sInputMark;
        sInputMark = values.get(1);
        int inputMark = Integer.parseInt(sInputMark);
        addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at writing the code to find the max and/or min?

Comment: For an idea, you can sort the list that on the basis of student marks and try getting the first and the last index of the list for the min and max respectively.

Comment: @SafeerAnsari You could do it in linear time. Sorting is unnecessary.

Comment: Hint: `IntStream.summaryStatistics()`.

Comment: just init 2 variables, with you max possible and you min possible, and compare them iteratatin your list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some indexed list since addStudent doesn't really tell me much (else just apply the logic to whatever you have):

```
private int getMax(ArrayList<Integer> marks) {
    int max = marks.get(0);
    int index = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < marks.size(); x++) {
        if(max < marks.get(x)) {
            max = marks.get(x);
            index = x;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Better solution:

> You could simply do Collections.max(list) – Imaginary Pumpkin

Yet I'll still leave mine to show the logic of how to find a max.

Comment: You could simply do `Collections.max(list)`

Comment: That is definitely a better solution.

Comment: Where does the work 'list' come from as my code is finding an error with it?

Comment: 'list' refers a collections object containing the marks. You currently have them stored somewhere in an object (I'm assuming at least) using your addStudent method. If you store them to a Collection type object, you can use the max function.